# Is there any way to modify a task from Task Scheduler programmatically with Python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule the execution of a Python file recurrently. However, the time when this process has to rerun changes every time.

I had thought of creating a task on Windows Task Scheduler, and then create a variable that updates when the task has to be triggered again

Answer (score 0):

The Task Scheduler is controlled by COM interfaces (CLSID_TaskScheduler).  Note that you can create a one-time task that deletes when it expires, then just have your app create a new task with the new time.  If you don't want to play with COM, you can use `os.system` to fire the `at` application, which enters a one-time task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use scheduler to do this. The trick part will be how you are going to change the execution time. If you can change your execution time with a method just do:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")


#schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at(yourmethod().do(job))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

And if you are expecting to input a new time manually, you can do:

```
def job_runner(time):
    schedule.every().day.at(time.do(job))
    indicator = False
indicator = True
time = #take user input
while indicator:
    time.sleep(1)
    job_runner(time)
    if not indicator:
          #hold the program and wait for new input
```

Official Documentation for Scheduler: [Here](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)